# How do I create more than a hello world with GitHub Pages?

Tags: github-pages

The instructions at [Git Hub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) show me how to create a Hello World website that just says "Hello World"

The instructions also say that the website can be hosted directly from my Git Hub repository.

I have created a HelloWorld.md file

How do I get it to display on my website?

I note that if I delete index.html then  GitHub generates a page based on readme.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding YAML front matter to your Markdown file. Your `HelloWorld.md` file should look something like this:

```
---
layout: default
---

Hello, world!
```

After this, GitHub Pages should generate a page for your Markdown file.

Answer (score 1):

By default, GitHub pages are rendered [with Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), so you would need to follow (in order to support markdown)

[Using Jekyll as a static site generator with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/)

See the doc and the typical [Jekyll repo structure](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/).

> I don't plan to install Jekyll locally. I have managed to get index.md showing, but there is no theme, even though _config.yml has one.

In that case, use another stack site generator for rendering your html page:
I would recommend [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/).

Comment: Thanks. I don't plan to install Jekyll locally. I have managed to get index.md showing, but there is no theme, even though _config.yml has one.

Comment: @kirsteng you need to generate your html pages then (from markdown). See my updated answer

Comment: but the instructions say "Hosted directly from your GitHub repository. Just edit, push, and your changes are live."  The link is in my question.  Thus I am thinking I do not need another site generator.  I don't actually want to use html pages. I just want to use Mark Down as advertised.

Comment: @kirsteng mardown is when used with Jekyll. If not, a site generator will gneerates the html pages for you.

Comment: So how do I push to github pages to generate helloworld.md using jekyll?

Comment: @kirsteng you need to follow https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/ and the documentation for that

Comment: @kirsteng here is an example of instructions using Jekyyl as well: http://clojurebridge.github.io/community-docs/docs/contribute/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137245/discussion-between-kirsten-g-and-vonc).